# "Call not sent" when adding a call on Samsung Galaxy S6

Tags: phone-app, google-voice

Sometimes, when I am on a call and try to add a call, I get an error message that reads, "Call not sent". It only happens sometimes, and I can't figure out the pattern. It seems to be related to the number I'm calling, but not in any obvious way. For example this morning 917.533.9562 worked but 212.784.8053 did not.

I am on a T-Mobile Samsung Galaxy S6 (SM-G920T), Android version 5.1.1, and I use Google Voice for all of my dialing.

If anyone can me solve this I will greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the update "broke" Google Voice on Note 4 and Galaxy phones (T-Mobile 5.1.1 update).

You can see information on this [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/voice/7v4o62rCRfI):

We're all hoping that someone (Google, T-Mobile, Samsung) will care enough to fix it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be my problem, since I am able to call out most of the time. It only happens when I try to conference in a second call, and even then it only happens sometimes.